# CSS: Help with position relative/absolute

Tags: css

I have a main menu bar at the top of my page. Now my `#LinkToMenu` fails at resizing and such, even if there's an `position: relative`. But it work fine if I set a specific width on the `#mainmenu` style, which I don't want it to. I even tried `width: auto`, with no luck.

```
<div id="mainmenu" style="position: relative;">

<div id="LinkToMenu" style="position: absolute; right: 130px; top: 10px;">
  <a href="home.php">Home</a>
</div>

<img src="images/mainmenu_logo3.png" style="position: absolute; top: 2px; left: 210px; ">
```

What's the problem? How can I solve this?

The image with nearly same settings works fine at resizing and so, but not the barlinks?

Comment: @meder yes I tried 100%, auto, and then i tried specific e.g 1200px; and then it sit perfect when resizing, but I do not wish to have specific width to the bar 1) ugly 2) will never be perfect "size" because then it depends on what screen you look at the site on 3) i think you get what I mean ..

Comment: Can you post a link to the whole page for us?  Some additional context might be useful.

Comment: Which browser is this happening in? All of them? And what do you mean by "resizing and such"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think #linkToMenu needs to have a width assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if I'm understanding your problem correctly, but I do do something similar and I do it like this (in a style sheet):
.header
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 6px 6px 5px 5px;
    height: 85px;
}

I seem to recall that the following absolute didn't work without the top and the left, so that the position is doing something.

Hope this helps

Comment: adding top and left didnt do anything to the issue

Answer (score 0):

not really sure I understand your question, but I think you should do the following:

```
#LinkToMenu{ position: absolute; right: 130px; top: 10px; float:right"}
#mainmenu{float:right; width:100%}
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`#mainmenu` effectively has no content - it's two children are `position:absolute`,  so are removed from the normal flow.  As is,  a DIV element is a block,  so should expand to the full width of the container,  although won't have any height.

Answer (score -1):

position:relative  tells the css engine that this div is the reference to the inner divs.

position: absolute tells the that this div is absoulte positioned to the outter div which has relative position or if not assigned the browser window.

unless you give a width and height to the reltive div u make actually not find the absolute div position itself correctly.

Comment: Why would the image I have with also positioning absolute setting work fine?